# Tooltips for not entirely displayed text in list-view *subitem* columns

Tags: c++, c, winapi, listview, tooltip

I have a list-view control in report mode. The list-view has three columns, and for some items the text in the third column can be very long, so it is not entirely displayed.

I'd like to show a tooltip just for the text in this third column that is not entirely displayed inside the list-view. Since the text can be long, I'd like a *multi-line* tooltip.

Is this something the list-view control can do automatically, after settings some flag/style?

If not, what path could I follow to implement this behavior?

---

**EDIT**

I've tried creating the list-view with the **`LVS_EX_INFOTIP`** extended style, and handled the **`LVN_GETINFOTIP`** notification (via `WM_NOTIFY`) in the parent window.

However, this notification is sent only for items, *not for subitems* (i.e. columns other than the first one), as explicitly noted in the [`NMLVGETINFOTIP` structure MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> **`iSubItem`**
>
> Type: **`int`**
>
> One-based index of the subitem to which this structure refers. If this
>   member is zero, the structure is referring to the item and not a
>   subitem. *This member is not currently used and will always be zero.*

Comment: I have withdrawn my answer, it doesn't look like there's any easy way to influence tooltips for the columns, the only relevant article I found was about using a Tooltip control in [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28885/CListCtrl-and-Displaying-a-Tooltip), but that's in MFC...